# Spring : Java heap space outOfMemory on bean creation's exception

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, dependency-injection, out-of-memory

I'm migrating my Spring dependencies injections, from XML declaration into the annotation style.

But now that I've migrated DAO, Services and Controllers, the server won't launch anymore :

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
```

I can see in the stacktrace (see below) there is a BeanCreationException, but i can't know which one because the OutOfMemory exception occurs on BeanCreationException's message construction.

I already tried to increase -Xmx and -XX:MaxPermSize JVM's argument, but i believe it's like an infinite loop or something like that. The application worked perfectly before the migration to annotation.

Do you have any idea how to know where the problem come from ?

Versions : Hibernate 3.1, Spring 2.5, Tomcat 7, JDK 7

Typical applicationContext.xml content (before) :

```
<bean id="fooDAO" class="foo.bar.fooDAO">
    <property name="sessionFactory">
        <ref bean="foo_factory" /> //extends LocalSessionFactoryBean
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="fooService" class="foo.bar.fooService">
    <property name="foodDAO" ref="fooDAO" />
</bean>

<bean id="fooControler" class="foo.bar.fooControler" autowire="byName">
     <property name="fooService" ref="fooService" />
</bean>
```

After migration :

@Repository on DAO, @Service on services and @Controller on controllers.

StackTrace :

```
mars 12, 2018 1:37:51 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase startInternal

GRAVE: A child container failed during start

java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:188)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1239)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:819)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1700)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1690)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
at java.util.Arrays.copyOf(Arrays.java:2367)
at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.expandCapacity(AbstractStringBuilder.java:130)
at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.ensureCapacityInternal(AbstractStringBuilder.java:114)
at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.append(AbstractStringBuilder.java:415)
at java.lang.StringBuffer.append(StringBuffer.java:232)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException.toString(BeanCreationException.java:154)
at java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:2849)
at java.lang.StringBuffer.append(StringBuffer.java:232)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException.toString(BeanCreationException.java:154)
at java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:2849)
at java.lang.StringBuffer.append(StringBuffer.java:232)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException.toString(BeanCreationException.java:154)
at java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:2849)
at java.lang.StringBuffer.append(StringBuffer.java:232)
at org.springframework.core.NestedExceptionUtils.buildMessage(NestedExceptionUtils.java:47)
at org.springframework.core.NestedRuntimeException.getMessage(NestedRuntimeException.java:67)
at java.lang.Throwable.getLocalizedMessage(Throwable.java:391)
at java.lang.Throwable.toString(Throwable.java:480)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException.toString(BeanCreationException.java:149)
at java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:2849)
at java.lang.StringBuffer.append(StringBuffer.java:232)
at org.springframework.core.NestedExceptionUtils.buildMessage(NestedExceptionUtils.java:47)
at org.springframework.core.NestedRuntimeException.getMessage(NestedRuntimeException.java:67)
at java.lang.Throwable.getLocalizedMessage(Throwable.java:391)
at java.lang.Throwable.toString(Throwable.java:480)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException.toString(BeanCreationException.java:149)
at java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:2849)
at java.lang.StringBuffer.append(StringBuffer.java:232)
at org.springframework.core.NestedExceptionUtils.buildMessage(NestedExceptionUtils.java:47)
at org.springframework.core.NestedRuntimeException.getMessage(NestedRuntimeException.java:67)
at java.lang.Throwable.getLocalizedMessage(Throwable.java:391)
at java.lang.Throwable.toString(Throwable.java:480)

mars 12, 2018 1:37:51 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase startInternal
GRAVE: A child container failed during start
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost]]
```

Comment: could you share your java config?

Comment: Try running it under debugger, with breakpoint set in "org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException.toString". At least partial error message should be visible in local variables.

Comment: @user158037 "The source attachment does not countain the source for the file BeanCreationException.class."

I used the Eclipse option "Change Attached Source" to point spring-beans.jar, but no result. Should i get an other jar with sources or something ? Thank you

Comment: @VladBochenin yes sure. But what do you mean by java config ?

Comment: based on stack trace it looks like you have a problem with `toString`. `BeanCreationException` doesn't use StringBuffer in `toString` but tries to append `relatedCause`. Seems the problem with `toString` in one of your beans.

Comment: @VladBochenin i just tried to comment the code of toString() in my beans (only 9 classes override it) and the result is still the same :/